# Why do I not see the "users and groups" option when managing an azure ad enterprise app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I've created a new subscription using the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program) and started to configure my test webapp registration.

As I'm working on some tutorials with Microsoft Identity Platform, I want to have a few users and a group to fool around with so I can have a clear understanding and presentation of the concept.

After creating 2 users other than myself and a group to hold everyone, I am trying to add the users to the app I've registered. As mentioned in the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups?WT.mc_id=UI_AAD_Enterprise_Apps_Support_L2_Overview#prerequisites) I have changed the `User assignment required` option to `Yes`.

However, after waiting a significant amount of time and even signing in using a private window I still don't see the option under my `Manage` category in the left panel.

#### What I expect to see (from a free tier directory)

[image]

#### What I actually see (using the dev program directory)

[image]

As you can see I'm also missing several other options in this dev program app. What do I need to change to make it show these options?

Comment: Hi Josh? Any updates?

Answer (score 3):

I guess your enterprise app is from a public client/ native app right?

Assign users and groups to a native app is meaningless. Because native app doesn't act as a service principal to ask for a token. It doesn't have a client secret. You won't get the app role from a token asked by a native app.

So the “users and groups” option is unavailable in this case.

Comment: I don't think I've done anything to indicate the app is a public app.

Comment: @JoshGust check in the Default client type, under the Authentication option in the menu (App Registrations).
There's an option there that indicate if the app is public or not.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your Application Registration (which is bound to your Enterprise App) has the following setting to `Yes`. Simply change the switch to `No`.

[image]